# onomatopoeia for the sound of spoons hitting on the plate when eating?

Tags: word-choice, onomatopoeia

Is there any word to describe this? 
I have tried inging but not sure if that is the best word.

Comment: Clinking? Spanging? Tinkling? Pinging?

Comment: Is the spoon dropped or is it under the control of the diner, but is hit against the plate in the course of eating?  Is the plate plastic, stonewear or china?  These variables would play a role in whether the sound is tinkling, dinging, thunking, clanking, etc.

Comment: Oh yes of course, sorry. The spoon is hit in the course of eating and the plates are bone china. The spoon is stainless steel.

Comment: "clackle" -----

Comment: Then Dan's suggested "clinking" or "tinkling" would be good for your sound and probably well-understood, too.

Comment: Definitely “*clink*” IMO.

Comment: @KristinaLopez  I am very glad that you didn't include *jingling* in your list. When you see this picture which we took in Kirkby Lonsdale on the Yorkshire Dales, last summer, you will understand why. My ten-year-old grandson couldn't stop laughing for the rest of the day. [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibu7m.jpg

Comment: @WS2 ha ha!  That's funny!!!

Answer (score 2):

*Clinking* is the onomatopoeia I most often see used with dishes. [Here's an example.](https://endkwote.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/dishes/)

If it was a very light sound, and there was a lot of it continually (such as a large, polite dinner party), I might call the cumulative sound *tinkling*.